# Почему голубцы?

Tags: этимология

Блюдо голубцы знают все, я думаю. Но мне интересно происхождение название.
Если предположить, что название происходит от голубого цвета, получается странное - голубцы, скорее, зеленые, но никак не голубые. Или же от названия голубя, но при чем тут голубь?
Или же происхождение названия какое-то совершенно другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Руси давно готовили похожее блюдо. Капустные листья начиняли рубленой говядиной вперемешку с пшенной кашей. Правда, называлось это блюдо галушей. В словаре Даля «галуша» и «голубцы» даны как синонимы. Почему же галуша превратилась в голубец? Откуда произошло название этого блюда? По мнению некоторых лингвистов, «голубец» – это трансформация «галуши».

По другой версии, это слово заимствовано из немецкого (по-нем. «голубец» - Kohlblatt).Но эту версию многие отвергают

Самое распространенное объяснение таково: сначала на Руси, в Белоруссии и Украине готовили галуши. Когда в 17-18 в. вошла в моду французская кухня, на столах знати появились зажаренные голуби. При готовке голубей обмазывали салом, заворачивали в капустный лист и жарили на решетке. Галуши превратились в ложных жареных голубей и получили прозвище «голубцы». Именно в то время в поваренных книгах появились первые рецепты голубцов.

http://www.povarenok.ru/blog/show/14810/

Answer (score 2):

Все просто... Листья молодой капусты имеют голубоватый (а они потом и кочан прикрывают), а точнее даже сизый цвет. Поле капустное издалека - синее.

http://yandex.ru/images/search?img_url=http%3A%2F%2Fshkolazhizni.ru%2Fimg%2Fcontent%2Fi5%2F5583.jpg&uinfo=sw-1366-sh-768-ww-991-wh-435-pd-1.25-wp-16x9_1680x945&_=1419836967890&viewport=wide&p=1&text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0&pos=32&rpt=simage&pin=1

http://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=caccc8930845af8634ab8981a321ff78-40-144&n=21

Эти листья для голубцов летом и использовали.

Answer (score 2):

Галушки, а не галуши, это тесто-клецки, в первом ответе вранье из ответчика mail.ru.

Answer (score 0):

Вот одно из мнений, но на мой взгляд, в происхождении этого названия может быть замешано слово голубить - ласкать, делать что-то с любовью, с нежностью. Голубец требует, чтобы его начинку ласково скатывали руками в комок, а затем нежно заворачивали в капустный лист.

[link text](http://edu-gotovim.ru/raznoe/113-proishozhdenie-golubcov.html)

Answer (score -1):

Никому не приходит в голову, что **ГОЛУБЦЫ** отражают в своём названии имя повара, который их внедрил? Вам всем знакомо русское имя **ГЛЕБ**, - первые русские святые *Борис* и ***Глеб***. И оба эти имени хазарские. Хазарские имена в то время были "*в моде*" на Руси. **ГОЛОБ** / **ГОЛУБ**  это аналог имени **ГЛЕБ**. Аналогично /*-ОЛО-* = *-ЛЕ-* ), как ***полон*** - ***плен***; ***полоскать*** - ***плескать***; ***молоко*** - ***млечный*** (Мл. Путь - наша Галактика), ***млекопитающиеся***; ***половой*** (орган) - ***плева*** (девственная); ***полоса*** - ***плёс*** (песчанный).

Когда я служил срочную службу в СА, у нас командир учебного взвода был капитан по фамилии *ГОЛУБ* (без **Ь**), родом из казачьей станицы на Кубани. Посмотрите еврейские=хазарские фамилии на *ГОЛОБ*- / *ГОЛОВ*- / *ГОЛУБ*-  по ссылке [link text](http://jmemory.org/) графа МЕМОРИАЛ, книзу страницы алфавитный указатель. (Примечание в иврите буква бет Б=В).  **ГОЛУБ  присутствует в  ГОЛУБЦАХ как форма имени ГЛЕБ**, *в наше время уже просто забытая*.  И не нужно приплетать сюда какие-то там *галушки*!